# Last Changed Date

Tags: sql

```
ID  DATE        AMT
A   20180401    110
A   20180301    110
A   20180201    100
A   20171010    90
B   20181001    90
B   20180901    90
B   20180707    80
```

My Output should be

```
ID  DATE       AMT  Result
A   20180401    110 20180201 
A   20180301    110 20180201
A   20180201    100 20171010
A   20171010    90  null
B   20181001    90  20180707
B   20180901    90  20180707
B   20180707    80  null
```

So i need to get the result column  date of Last value different from current value with in same ID

so if we take the first record in this case current AMT value is 110 and next record also has 110 and the next record is 100 which is different from current value so I need to get that date -

I have used 
LAST_VALUE ( DATE) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, AMT ORDER BY ID ) AS LASTVALUE -I'm getting the date for the records with same Amount

This is after the 
LAST_VALUE ( DATE) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, AMT ORDER BY ID ) AS LASTVALUE2

```
ID;DAT;AMT;LASTVALUE2   -After Last Value
A;Mar 1, 2018;130;Mar 1, 2018
A;Feb 1, 2018;110;Jan 1, 2018
A;Jan 1, 2018;110;Jan 1, 2018
A;Nov 1, 2017;140;Nov 1, 2017
B;Jun 1, 2018;110;Apr 1, 2018
B;May 1, 2018;110;Apr 1, 2018
B;Apr 1, 2018;110;Apr 1, 2018
B;Mar 1, 2018;130;Mar 1, 2018
ID;DAT;AMT;PREV_DIFF_VALUE -After Lag
A;Nov 1, 2017;140;?
A;Jan 1, 2018;110;Nov 1, 2017
A;Feb 1, 2018;110;Jan 1, 2018
A;Mar 1, 2018;130;Feb 1, 2018
B;Mar 1, 2018;130;?
B;Apr 1, 2018;110;Mar 1, 2018
B;May 1, 2018;110;Apr 1, 2018
B;Jun 1, 2018;110;May 1, 2018
```

The third record should be Nov 1 2017 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please indicate the version of SQL you are using?

Comment: What's your DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...)?

Comment: Where are you getting the new dates in your latest example? Where did November come from? Is that just the data you have or is that a new calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*, 
       max(case when result <> next_result then date end) over (partition by id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
from (select t.*,
             lead(result) over (partition by a order by b) as next_result
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon ..I was thinking something on those lines as well ..Sorry for the delayed response

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT s1.ID
    , FORMAT(s1.theDate,'MM-dd-yyyy') AS theDate
    , s1.Amt
    --, s1.PrevAmt
    , CASE 
        WHEN Amt <> prevAmt 
        THEN FORMAT(
          LAG(theDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY theDate )
          ,'MM-dd-yyyy' ) 
        END AS prevDate
FROM (
  SELECT ID, theDate, Amt
    , LAG(AMT) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY theDate) AS prevAmt 
  FROM t1 
) s1
ORDER BY ID, theDate DESC
```

This should give:

> ```
> ID | theDate    | Amt | prevDate  
> :- | :--------- | --: | :---------
> A  | 10-10-2017 |  90 | null      
> A  | 04-04-2018 | 110 | null      
> A  | 03-03-2018 | 110 | 02-02-2018
> A  | 02-02-2018 | 100 | 10-10-2017
> B  | 10-10-2018 |  90 | null      
> B  | 09-09-2018 |  90 | 07-07-2018
> B  | 07-07-2018 |  80 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fe26d50ba8ef18fae4bc824c109c121)*

For rows that don't have a previous row to pull the `date` from, it will return a `NULL` in the `prevDate` field.